# My salmon burgers are bland

Tags: fish, spices, hamburgers, salmon

I just tried to fry a salmon fillet and eat it as a I would a hamburger patty: with bread, cucumber and tomato. No matter my seasoning, I keep finding the taste bland.

What could I do to enhance the taste when it comes to spices and other ingredients?

Comment: Fish is a milder experience than a regular burger. Maybe use a little Zen and pause for a minute before consumption in order to enjoy it for what it is.

Comment: Just in case it came off that way, I meant no sarcasm. Personally, it's an effort to appreciate milder foods. Because I instantly love most anything with ka-boom like Mexican, Thai, Cajun, or Hunan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would squeeze a lemon over the fish when it was done, and then make a sauce for it. You can do like an Aioli or flavored mayonnaise, using ingredients such as capers, dill, lemon etc.. whatever you would normally like on regular cooked salmon.

Also, you will find a difference in taste between a farm raised and wild-caught salmon. Wild caught salmon have redder flesh (although some places have started dyeing farmed salmon), and have a much stronger salmon flavor than farm raised salmon.

Answer (score 3):

Why not prepare the "burger" more like a crab cake? Cook the salmon, break into smaller pieces, mix together with seasoning and binding agents, then form into a patty, put a sear on it, and enjoy?

Answer (score 2):

A marinade is always good to counter blandness. Try marinating it for a few hours in soy sauce, garlic, ginger, lime (or lemon) and some chili. Your fillet should come out anything but bland.

Comment: I would warn against marinating fish for a few hours -- it might get mushy from the acids. But definitely try marinating it for 1/2 to 1 hour before cooking.

Answer (score 2):

You could substitute some of the salt for fish sauce (aka nam pla) for added umami.

Answer (score 1):

add some spice to your seasoning, perhaps a dash of mustard.

Comment: I always add about a Tablespoon of dijon mustard to my salmon patties (one can's worth of salmon).

Comment: Thanks, Covar. Which specific spices do you recommend besides mustard?

Comment: Almost anything you might add to Salmon or a burger.  I would suggest Old bay, some kind of chili powder, or pepper flakes.

Comment: @TimN I'd recommend capers.